# How to enable Parse Local datastore in Fragment

Tags: android, parse-platform, fragment, datastore

can anyone please help me? I am trying to enable Parse Local Datastore in a fragment but its throwing out an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context, String, String)`. Below is the code I use which works perfectly fine in an Activity but not in Fragment and I know the getActivity context is not null since the second line works.

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getActivity());
Parse.initialize(getActivity(), DeveloperKey.ParseAppID, DeveloperKey.ParseClientKey);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised using `pin()` automatically saves to the local datastore so there was no need to explicitly use `enableLocaldatastore()`. With this, I can query from `localdatastore` and get the cached result.

Answer (score 1):

you have to move your code related to Parse initialization to the Application class. Make class extending Application, add it to manifest and then in the onCreate() of you application call

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getActivity());
Parse.initialize(getActivity(), DeveloperKey.ParseAppID, DeveloperKey.ParseClientKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your logcat error you just need to interchange your code.

```
 Parse.initialize(getActivity(), DeveloperKey.ParseAppID, DeveloperKey.ParseClientKey);
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getActivity());
```

When your parse is enables after that you'l be able to enable your local database for it.

Comment: Have you clean your project?

Comment: Had tried that but no effect. I am going to add what I did to get the local datastore. thanks for your help @Piyush.

Comment: The logcat said that enable needs to be called before initialize, and that's what @saintjab was doing. You just reversed what the logcat was saying.

Comment: @Piyush is wrong about the order enableLocalDatastore should be called before initializing but above error can be resolved by adding it during initializing . See my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getActivity());
```

is an old way of enabling local datastore.

Now you have to do like this.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.parse_api_key))
                .clientKey(null)
                .server("YOUR_SERVER_URL/") // The trailing slash is important.
        .enableLocalDataStore().build()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading:

```
implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:x.xx.x"
```

To a newer version. Like this:

How android ide did help me out:
[image: How android ide did help me out]